# regex sql optimization

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a system (sysB) that stores names without any rules on the names and I have another system that has objects with ids (sysA). When data comes from sysA to sysB, the names that are put in there will be like "BIN-the id-and some other stuff".

On sysB, I get a list of ids from sysA then perform a regex query like this:

```
select id
from mytable
where "mytable"."name"::text ~ '(^BIN-8178-.*)|(^BIN-2345-.*)';
```

I've noticed that the query becomes so slow as the list grows bigger.

If the list of ids has 800 ids, the query takes 18 seconds!

I tried changing the field to be indexed; it did not help.
I know that adding this index to the other system as a new field can speed it up but I was wondering if there is a way to speed up the query without changing the schema.
Also note that the systems are independent so I cannot do join.

Comment: You might try splitting up the alternation with either an `or` or a `union`.

Comment: pls tag with RDBMS

Comment: I added the `postgresql` tag based on the usage of the `::` casting operator and `~`. If you are using something different, then please remove that tag and add the correct tag for the database product you are using.

Comment: As you are looking for strings starting with `BIN` you could add another filter `where name like 'BIN%'` which can make use of an index. Then the regex only has to be applied to those rows.

Comment: It would help if you can show us the complete `create table` statement including all indexes for the table in question. (**[edit]** your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it) do not put code in comments)

Comment: Try creating an index expression on the leftmost 8 characters of the `name` column and then matching to only the leftmost 8 characters of each of the values to be searched for.  Why are those values hard-coded into SQL rather than in a second table that can be joined to `mytable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select id
from mytable
where "mytable"."name" like 'BIN-8178%'
```

with an index on `mytable(name)`.  Postgres should be able to use the index for this `LIKE` pattern.

If the index is being used, it should also be used for:

```
select id
from mytable
where "mytable"."name" like 'BIN-8178%' or
      "mytable"."name" like 'BIN-2345%';
```

However, indexes can be finicky and you might need to use `union all`:

```
select id
from mytable
where "mytable"."name" like 'BIN-8178%' 
union all
select id
from mytable
where "mytable"."name" like 'BIN-2345%';
```

Comment: Using like instead of regex was still as slow; however, when I used union all, it got so much faster. It went from 20 seconds down to 100ms. thanks

Comment: @max . . . That is interesting.  Postgres should have been smart enough to use the index with the `or`.  I guess that hasn't been implemented yet.